# Spring common property reference with different value per application

Tags: java, spring

I have a bean which is used across all projects (different war files).
That particular bean requires a property appname (to know which app is using the bean).
How can i configure this?

I tried passing the value in the following way:

```
<bean id="appNameProperty" class="java.util.Properties">
    <property name="appName" value="app1" />
</bean>
```

Bean definition:

```
<bean id="someClass" class="someClass">
    <property name="appName" value="#{appNameProperty.appName}" />
</bean>
```

Where appName is supposed to be a String value.
I get the following exception while deploying my app:

```
Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'appName' of bean class [java.util.Properties]: Bean property 'appName' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

Comment: The exception is telling you what is wrong... The `Properties` object doesn't have such a property and neither does your `someClass`. The class needs to have a `setAppName` method else there is no property. A property != field.

Comment: @M.Deinum is there a way to achieve what i want?
as in declaring some property in the config file of all modules, and accessing that in my someClass bean?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the VM arguments you could use the property placeholder configurer as mentioned above. If the app name is fixed for every application and you are using war-files everywhere you could add e.g. "/WEB-INF/config" to the list of the properties location and place there a properties file containing the app-name:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <!-- further locations -->
            <value>WEB-INF/config/*.properties</value>
            <!-- further locations -->
        </list>
    </property>
    <!-- further configuration as needed -->
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

```
<bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer"   
 class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">  
 <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
 <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true" />
</bean>  

<bean id="yourBean" class="path.to.your.BeanClass"> 
   <property name="appName"   value="#{systemProperties['appName']}"/>
</bean>
```

All you need to do is pass VM arguement -DappName=abcApp while starting the app.

ref [PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html)

Comment: any alternative apart from using VM argument?

Comment: how you are loading application specific configurations?

Comment: The value of appName is different for every war file.
I have decided to make use of property file in each war file where i'll have appName property.